# Database export to separate JSON files with Sprinb Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I want to export every entity from database to separate json file. Is that possible with Spring batch?

Comment: Yes it is very possible. Without more information, I would guess this isn't something you want to use spring-batch for though

Comment: @SamF I was speaking theoretically just to test concept. But what I really need is separate json files for grouped objects by some criteria. I have around 180000 objects that actualy need to be exported, so to optimize process I would need them grouped in several files.